# How to get delve url of SharePoint Online user using Ms flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, delve

i just want to get delve url user profile. I've try the following by using flow. But, it direct me to the delve main home, instead of specific user.

https://tenenat-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?p=**EmployeeName[Email]**.com&v=work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get the delve url of current user, you can hit below url:

   https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx?v=profile
2. To get the delve url of another user, you can hit below url:

   https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?p=user.name%40tenantname.com&v=work

   So, if a user's name is Emily and valid email address like Emily@abc.com or Emily@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com, then url be like:

   https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?p=Emily%40abc.com&v=work

   or

   https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?p=Emily%40tenantname.onmicrosoft.com&v=work